# Lightning Scheduler Custom Questions for the Screens

Tags: lightning-scheduler

i am trying to configure lightning flow for guest appointment Scheduling. I want to change the questions to ask in the screens, like instead of **Select Work Type Groups**, I want to ask **How can we assist you?**, can we modify the screen components in that way ?

Answer (score 0):

Use Rename Tabs & Labels. See quip below for configuration options available out of the box
https://salesforce.quip.com/FspIAaOkn80a#KIJACAZ1seg

Comment: well, @user93990 that will just change the standard object labels not the headings, so instead of asking 'Select Work Type Groups', I wanted to ask 'How can we assist you'. Anyway, I had to create custom component screens, as these headings are not exposed as design attributes in the standard screen components. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

we ended up creating custom components for the screen to change the questions and also for other custom things as well.